# How to create a MySQL search query to include abbreviations

Tags: php, mysql, search, subquery

I'm using PHP and MySQL. Right now I'm searching my database with a series of LIKEs and UNIONs, so a query, based on what the user types may look like
`WEHRE title LIKE '%Term1%' AND title LIKE '%Term2%' UNION ... WHERE author LIKE ...`

You get the point. I add the wildcard around each term, and a term is determined by a space. And then, when the results are returned, I highlight the term they searched. Simple enough, not trying to compete with Google here. :)

Now I've added a field which holds Bible references where the user may use abbreviations, such as "Mt" or "Mt." or "Matt" or "Matt." or Matthew. Now I can easily reduce that from 5 to 3 by stripping periods out of any query, but what is the best way to include the other ones?

Furthermore, whether they search Mt or Matt or Matthew, I still want to highlight the full word Matthew, so again, I'm dealing with how do I link it together.

The only solution I'm coming up with is making a 3D array and looping saying, if I have a Matt or Mt, change that to Matthew, times 66 for each book. Is this a good way to do it, or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should construct a table of possible aliases, although to be fair, the bible has probably been quite extensively indexed by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be, to construct a table to hold groups of aliases:

```
CREATE TABLE AliasGroup ( Alias NVARCHAR(50), GroupId INT )
INSERT INTO AliasGroup
VALUES ( 'Mt', 1 )
      ,( 'Matt', 1 )
      ,( 'Matthew', 1 )
      ,( 'Lk', 2 )
      ,( 'Luke', 2 )
      /* --- etc --- */
```

Then, for each search term that exists in the AliasGroup-table, also highlight all other Aliases with the same GroupId.

Now, to search for both 'Mt', 'Matt' and 'Matthew', when only one of them is the actual search-term, a quick-and-dirty query would look something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
CROSS JOIN
   (SELECT Alias FROM AliasGroup 
    WHERE GroupId = (SELECT GroupId FROM AliasGroup WHERE Alias = $term1)) A
WHERE title LIKE '%' + Alias + '%'
```

This is not an ideal approach, however, and it will probably not perform very good, because of the `LIKE` operator in the WHERE-clause. It would be much better if you constructed an index table of unique terms beforehand. This is easily created for example using PHP - simply loop through all records of your table and split all titles, etc., by individual words. Remove punctuation, and store the individual words in your index table together with the ID of the original record. Whenever you encounter a term that has one or more aliases, also write each of the aliases in your index table. Then do all your searches against the index table:

```
SELECT Id
FROM IndexTable 
WHERE Term = $term1
```

Comment: So then what would the query look like? I've never used something like that before.

Comment: I like the suggestion of having an index table, but I'm trying to figure out how to form the layout, considering a title could be anywhere from 2 words to 30. So would I just have a table 40 columns wide that would fit all the data I want to search, and each row would have an index? And then how would I go about making sure that a partial word would still be picked up? Aren't I back to LIKEs again? Sorry for the naiveness, although I'm not new to this, I am self taught, so more complex things like this aren't so readily known. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: Well, the index table I'm thinking of, only has 2 columns: One that holds search terms, and the other is a foreign key referencing your articles. To create the index table, loop through all titles, split them up into individual words, and add those words to the index table. In this step, also add any aliases, so when you encounter the word 'Mt' in a title, also add 'Matt' and 'Matthew', referencing the same article. If you want to take this in a whole different direction, consider looking into the Full-Text Search-functions of MySql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Okay, I see how that would work, but then wouldn't I have 300 rows that are simply "The"? Or is that not such a bad thing considering I already have 300 rows with that in it anyways? Perhaps it would be better to reverse the columns, and put the words as the index, and a comma delimited second field to hold the IDs? And then comes the part where if somebody is searching for "theol" because they're too lazy to type out "theology", I still want it to return a result, but then I'm back to LIKE queries.

Comment: Still hoping you might be able to answer my last question.

Comment: @David : You are right, that my proposed solution will result in many rows containing the same word. To save storage space, you could create surrogate integer keys for all distinct words. That is how most full text search engines work internally, anyway. Also, you would typically filter out common words such as "The", as they don't add any value to your search queries. I don't like the solution of storing a comma delimited string of article ID references, as this requires a lot of work in order to decode. With the functionality you need, consider using the built-in full-text search in MySQL.